# Android Calendar Issues

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I have a calendar in android and I would like to round it to the midnight of the the current day (12 A.M or 00:00:00) below is the code that I am using, however, when I run it, the time is always 4 hours past 12 (04:00:00) I do not know what is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setLenient(false);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), c.getTimeInMillis() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("Day in Millis", c.getTimeInMillis() + "");
```

Comment: Is your phone set to UTC-4 Timezone?

Comment: It is set to GMT-04:00, Eastern Daylight Time

Comment: ok, I figured it out, your comment really helped, thank you!

Comment: Please post your answer